# Background function that plays audio only works sometimes on device , all the time on simulator swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, background-process

I have this in my viewDidLoad :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appEnteredBackgound), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
```

To handle when my app is closed. The function appEnteredBackgound plays audio from a non AV library. This code works every-time in simulator when closing and opening the app. Yet on a real device only sometimes. Other times on real device the audio just stops playing, any ideas on why that is?

Answer (score 0):

Your notification for the state where your app is in background but still active....it will be called when app enters background like on click of home button......do not expect it to be called when terminate your app.
Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground.

If you want to play or resume laying your audio even after termination of your app you should got with

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```